# ngInputTags input text becomes hidden on many tags

Tags: angularjs

When I added a lot of tags and I continue adding input text becomes hidden at far right.

```
Here is a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/96PsKv?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple hack if anyone has the same issue. I know this is not the best solution but if anyone has the same issue maybe will help.

```
    var tagHost = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('host'));
    tagHost[0].focus();
    tagHost.triggerHandler('click');
```

Doing *focus()* on input text wasn't worked all the time really worked a few times.